# Less - compiling without merging files

Tags: css, less

I am new to Less but as I have compiled less files its merging them together into one. For example I have a **custom.less** and using on a Class form Font-Awesome's less **@fa-var-check-circle**. If I check the output CSS File I can see that the less File Font-AweSome is also compiled instead just to take the **@fa-var-check-circle**. How can I compile each less for itself?

Comment: Well, if your `custom.less` includes (via `@import`) font-awesome files that are meant to output CSS code then this code is supposed to be included into your final CSS too. If you need to use only font-awesome variables include only its [variables file](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/variables.less) instead of the [whole lib](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/font-awesome.less).

Comment: Aletrnatively you can experiment with [`reference` option](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference), but in general it's nothing but a back-door invented to reuse existing CSS files and not really for Less libraries.